# How to limit Google Direction API request with package name

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-directions-api

I implemented Google Direction API in my app like below and it's work great.

```
DirectionsApi.newRequest(geoContext)
                        .origin(origin)
                        .destination(destination)
                        .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                        .language("fa")
                        .await();
```

but the problem is **how to limit API** for my application. I tried to make a public key that limits to **app package and sign key** but it **didn't work**.
I came into this result that **Google Direction API can't limit with the package name and SHA1** of sign key like what we do with Google Map.

I'm curious about any way to limit my API usage to my package name and sign key like what I do with Google map API.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Directions API web service. Web services do not support Android app restrictions on API keys. The only possible restriction for web service requests is the IP restriction.

It is supposed that web services are executed on backend servers, so you can limit API key to your server's IP address. In case of mobile app in order to protect your API key you should establish an intermediate server and send all requests to Google from this server, so you app should send request to intermediate server that will send requests to Google and pass responses back to app.

Comment: Can I use Direction API any other way than Web Service? Something like what we use with google map.

Comment: Google Maps Android API v2 doesn't include any client side service for Directions. The only option at the moment is using web services via http requests.